# File Does Not Exist in Amazon EMR even though it tries to upload it

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, hadoop-yarn, emr, amazon-emr

I used Amazon EMR to create an `emr-4.0.0 cluster`:

However, whenever I try to submit a spark application on it, it fails and gives the following error:

`File does not exist: hdfs://ip-xx-xx-xxx-xx.ec2.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1441035668468_0001/spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.6.0-amzn-0.jar`

This is even though earlier in the log it uploads **this exact same** file without issuing any error message:

`2015-08-31 15:43:29,070 INFO [main] yarn.Client (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Uploading resource file:/usr/lib/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.6.0-amzn-0.jar -> hdfs://ip-xx-xx-xxx-xx.ec2.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1441035668468_0001/spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.6.0-amzn-0.jar`

(I've verified that the source file indeed exists at /usr/lib/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.6.0-amzn-0.jar on the master machine).

The command I use is:

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn-cluster --class com.sundaysky.ads.spark.cluster.TrackingLogsAnalysis /tmp/oz/AdsTests-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

BTW, I've noticed that this uses `Java 1.7` (even though it's the newest EMR version by Amazon), but I don't think that is relevant.

Do you have any ideas what could be the issue, or alternatively, how to debug the problem? I've tried many way of adding parameters to the spark-submit command to get TRACE level messages from yarn-client, but without success.

Thanks,
Oz

Answer (score 1):

So, after talking to Amazon support, in case anyone ever comes across a simliar issue:

The specific problem in my case was that my logic jar (not the spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.6.0-amzn-0.jar, which is provided by Amazon) was compiled with Java 8, while the machine only supported Java 7.

This was **not** reflected in the error log for the step, but rather in the stderr log for the step's container, where a following message appeared:

```
15/08/31 15:43:41 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Starting the user application in a separate Thread Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:     com/xxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/MyClass : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
```

If you encounter a similar problem, and the step's log files do not provide an answer, you should also look in the container's log:

- Go to Amazon's EMR web page.
- Click your cluster to open the Cluster Details screen
- Near the "Log URI" there should be a folder icon, click it to open the logs
- Go to "containers" and continue going down the one matching your task
- Check the stderr.gz and stdout.gz for issues

HTH,
Oz